# count distinct values multiple col

Tags: mysql, count, distinct

I have this table
(model - not table in SQL, all keys are joined to a real table but I need to count keys which exist in this model.)

```
key1   key2  key 3
v1     d1    t1
v2     d2    t1
v3     d1    t4
v1     d3    t8
v1     d2    t4
```

The result needs to return

```
key1 v1 3
key1 v2 1
key1 v3 1
key2 d1 2
```

fiddle for test
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c102f

I can't select all the keys one by one, because the number of keys = 79 and rows num  = 1 115 260

one by one select process takes 2 mins

Answer (score 1):

You can't groupby separate columns in a single select statement as the first group would effect the 2nd etc.

There is no other way besides selecting them one by one, but
if you just want a to get everything into one result you can use **union**

```
(select 'key1' AS column_origin, key1, count(key1) from TestTable group by key1)
union all
(select 'key2', key2, count(key2) from TestTable group by key2)
union all
(select 'key3', key3, count(key3) from TestTable group by key3);
```

Comment: if i am use union, i am can't see what key was count. This values and keys - options for filter and i am need count elements in result for each option

Comment: @Gelid There, I fixed it. @mimzee Use `union all` when results will be distinct anyway or you don't want the implicit `distinct` of `union` to filter results. For performance reasons...